# Diagram.contextMenu value is not an instance of Adornment

Tags: javascript, gojs, adornment

I have the following definition for a `contextMenu` on my Go `diagram`

```
SeatingMapGraphicsRef.contextMenu =
$(go.Adornment, "Vertical",
  // no binding, always visible button:
  $("ContextMenuButton",
    $(go.TextBlock, "Hold Seats"),
    { click: function(e, obj) {
      holdSeatsInDragSelect();
    } }),
           $("ContextMenuButton",
    $(go.TextBlock, "Select Seats"),
    { click: function(e, obj) {
    } }),
            $("ContextMenuButton",
    $(go.TextBlock, "Lock Seats"),
    { click: function(e, obj) {
    } }),
            $("ContextMenuButton",
    $(go.TextBlock, "Cancel"),
    { click: function(e, obj) {
      var diagram = e.diagram;
                diagram.hideContextMenu();
    } })
);
```

However when I write this, I get the following error:

```
Error: Diagram.contextMenu value is not an instance of Adornment
```

How exactly is this the case?

Here is my definition of `SeatingMapGraphicsRef`

```
    function generateMap() {
    SeatingMapGraphicsRef =
    GO(go.Diagram, "mapBodyDiv",  // the DIV HTML element
        {
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
            initialAutoScale:go.Diagram.Uniform,
            "toolManager.mouseWheelBehavior": go.ToolManager.WheelZoom
        });
```

And finally here is the reference page on ContextMenus from which I took the contextMenu definition on a `diagram` level.

http://gojs.net/latest/intro/contextMenus.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you started to use:

```
var GO = go.GraphObject.make;
```

Instead of the (common in the samples):

```
var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
```

Presumably because you're using jQuery too.

It will probably work if you change all the `$` to `GO` in your Adornment definition

Comment: @Simon_Sarris Thank you. Not it only throws an error when I try to call `showContextMenu` on the `SeatingMapGraphicsRef`.In the following way: `SeatingMapGraphicsRef.toolManager.contextMenuTool.showContextMenu()`

Comment: which gives me this error: referring to that line: `Error: ContextMenuTool.showContextMenu:contextmenu value is not an instance of Adornment: undefined`

Comment: ah! it looks like I need to pass it an Adornment. Should I just pass the `GO` definition of the adornment above in to the function?

Comment: I try to passing `SeatingMapGraphicsRef.contextMenu` but I get `ContextMenuTool.showContextMenu:obj value is not an instance of GraphObject: undefined`